# Python, Strange behaviour of time()

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, benchmarking

I had the following code in python, when I run it with `time_limit` = 0.5 I get the following output:

```
def run_step(self, env, agent_id, time_limit):
    self.start = time.time()
    self.agent_id = agent_id
    self.time_limit = time_limit
    self.epsilon = 0.99
    prev_op, curr_op, depth = None, None, 1
    while True:
        total_used_time = time.time() - self.start
        print(f's1: {total_used_time}')
        if total_used_time >= self.epsilon * self.time_limit:
            break
        print(f's2: {total_used_time}')
        _, op = self._run_step(env, self.agent_id, depth)
        depth += 1
        print(f's3: {total_used_time}')
    print(depth)
    return prev_op

s1: 1.1920928955078125e-06
s2: 1.1920928955078125e-06
s3: 1.1920928955078125e-06
s1: 0.4996809959411621
2
```

which makes me so confused... why calculating `total_used_time` takes around 0.5 seconds?

What's more interesting is that if I change the value of  `time_limit`  for something like 3 then the output is:

```
s1: 9.5367431640625e-07
s2: 9.5367431640625e-07
s3: 9.5367431640625e-07
s1: 2.9748899936676025
2
```

And as you can see now it's taking around 3 seconds... what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `total_used_time` when you print `s2` and `s3`; you're just printing out the measurement that you took at the start of the loop.  For `s2` and `s3` you should just redo the subtraction inline:

```
def run_step(self, env, agent_id, time_limit):
    start = time.time()
    epsilon = 0.99
    prev_op, curr_op, depth = None, None, 1
    while True:
        total_used_time = time.time() - start
        print(f's1: {total_used_time}')
        if total_used_time >= epsilon * time_limit:
            break
        print(f's2: {time.time() - start}')
        _, op = self._run_step(env, agent_id, depth)
        depth += 1
        print(f's3: {time.time() - start}')
    print(depth)
    return prev_op
```

You didn't share what `self._run_step` does, but you might easily have bugs there related to your instance attributes leaking state in between function calls (e.g. having `run_step` and `_run_step` share a single `self.start` value even though logically they will have different starting times); in the above code I just left all the local variables as local, which should make that type of bug impossible.